# Can you tell me the meaning of "/g" here

Tags: javascript, regex

When I've studied the code given by my professor, I found a line that I do not quite understand.

The code is like this:

```
textclean = textclean.replace(/ your /g," ");
```

I think the meaning is to replace `your` with a space so we can delete it by `split(" ")`; but what is the meaning of `/g`?

Why can't we use:

```
textclean = textclean.replace(your, " ");
```

Comment: Read the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) !

Comment: A new programmer may not realize that [Javascript supports regular expression patterns as literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) or be familiar with regular expressions. I think in that case they could be forgiven for not knowing what to Google for. Your professor should have explained them before using this notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means replace `globally`, not only the 1st occurance. If you have "Foo your bar mooo your example" then without the /g only the 1st " your " would be replaced.